# Sending data from listener (of httpRequestObserver) to addon panel (iframe)

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firebug, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to create a fire-bug like extension for firefox which is actually dev-tool extension. I have registered `httpRequestObserver` to observe `http-on-examine-response` event. I have a listener with below method implemented.

```
onDataAvailable: function(request, context, inputStream, offset, count) {
    //I get the request URL using request.name
    var responseData = getResponseData(); // gets data from inputStream
    // Now I need to render this responseData into panel's iframe
}
```

I have created the above script as a module and included it in `main.js`. **I could not find out how the data from this script could be sent to the script included in panel's HTML.**
I read about `Content Script` and `port.emit` & `port.on` but I think `Content Script` won't come into picture since I don't want to touch the actual page's DOM. Want I want to do is intercept the HTTP response and log it into devtool panel.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the response string received and make a data url out of it. Then with your content script do a `document.write(dataurl)` or do `window.location = dataurl`.

How to make dataurl:

```
var responseData = getResponseData();
var dataurl = 'data:text/html,' + encodeURIComponent(responseData);
```

I hear that widgets in sdk have a `content` option where you can specify this data url:

> 'content' option in panel, which would enable you to specify HTML content directly, as you can with a widget, as a result of which I've raised [bug 692675](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=692675).

Can also be done like this:

```
var HTML = '<html><p>Hi there</p></html>';
var panel = require('panel').Panel({
   contentURL: "data:text/html, " + encodeURIComponent(HTML)
});
panel.show();
```

Comment: This worked. But it creates a new Panle and shows, obviously this is what the code says. But I already have a `devtoolTabDefinition` defined and registered it to `gDevTools`. I am trying to send data to the HTML referred by [url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/DevToolsAPI#ToolDefinition) property of this tab definition.

Comment: Are you asking how to reuse an existing panel?

Comment: Not a panel actually but thanks I figured a way out.

Comment: Can you share your final solution below so it can help others plz. thx

Comment: Note: the widget api is being deprecated and then nuked from high orbit, the replacement in most cases is the button apis. IMO the use of a data uri here is legit.

Comment: @ NiranjanBorawake the button api @canuckistani speaks of is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/ui  but canuck man, isn't the above not using widget? It's using panel api, that continues to live on right?

Comment: As of now, I have thought of using an eventing mechanism to notify the  addon once responseData is available which should then updated itself. I'll post the solution once I implement it.

Comment: @Noitidart I am still facing similar kind of issue, have created a new question for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25114970/firefox-addon-sending-data-from-main-js-to-dev-tool-tab