# Firefox Addon: Sending data from main.js to dev tool tab

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to implement an addon that will intercept the HTTP response and then log it on to dev tool tab similar to the way XHRs are logged into web console.

Addon code has following files:

```
data/index.html
lib/main.js
```

I have defined `devtoolTabDefinition` :

```
devtoolTabDefinition = {
    id: "logger",
    ordinal: 3,
    icon: "chrome://browser/skin/devtools/inspector-icon.png",
    url: self.data.url("index.html"),
    label: "HRRL",
    tooltip: "HTTP Request Response Logger",
    // Rest of the code
```

I have registered an observer,`HttpResponseListener` from `Ci.nsIObserverService` to observe `"http-on-examine-response"`. `HttpResponseListener` intercepts the responses and I get the response string in it's `onDataAvailable` method.

I need to send rather add this response string to the dev tool tab's index.html.

AFAIK I don't have to use content script because I have nothing to do with the main page window. I just need to intercept the response and log it in dev tool tab.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you look [at the example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/DevToolsAPI#Examples), the communications channel is set up in the build method, which you don't show in your code. You can see a working example of this approach here:

https://github.com/canuckistani/jetpack-devtools-template/blob/master/lib/main.js#L42-L51

*Aside: starting with Firefox 34 (now in nightly) there will be new devtools apis to make this all easier, for a [really simple example see here](https://github.com/canuckistani/gulp-dt-fx/blob/master/index.js).

Comment: Thanks canuckistani. In the [main.js](https://github.com/canuckistani/jetpack-devtools-template/blob/master/lib/main.js) of your addon in `build` method you have accessed `iframeWindow.RDPMonitorView`. How and where is `RDPMonitorView` set into `iframeWindow`? Is it from [rdp-monitor.xul](https://github.com/canuckistani/jetpack-devtools-template/blob/master/chrome/content/rdp-monitor.xul) where you include a script `rdp-monitor.js`? If yes, will and how can this be done in case of HTML rather than xul?

Comment: That's roughly correct. Keep in mind this isn't my code sample! Another example by the same developer that uses hmtl is the ember inspector: [main.js](https://github.com/rpl/ember-extension/blob/experimental/firefox_devtools_addon/dist_firefox/lib/main.js) and the [panel definition](https://github.com/rpl/ember-extension/blob/experimental/firefox_devtools_addon/dist_firefox/lib/devtool-panel.js). Again, with Firefox 34 this is all going to improve.